# Facebook Apps for In-house use

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

We are currently in development for a couple apps that allow someone to post in the companies Fan Page, so we need the manage_page and publish permissions, which require approval, in this case the apps will NOT be made public (only 1 person will use it at all times), so my question is, can i keep using it in development mode or do i need to still go through the approval process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking in the Facebook Group the consensus is, use your app on development mode. Thought i'd post this in case someone else is wondering this.